# how to make clm application to connect DB on tcps port

Tags: oracle12c, websphere-liberty, mutual-authentication

we are using clm 6.0.3 with liberty profile and oracle db 12c for our applications.

Java.runtime= Java™ SE Runtime Environment (pxa6470_27sr3fp40-201604220_01 (SR3 FP40))
our IBM clm applications are hosted on Websphere Liberty Server 8.5.5.9 (wlp-1.0.12.cl50920160227-1523)

java version - 1.7.0_75
ojdbc driver-ojdbc7.jar

Implementation setup

---

We want to enable mutual ssl authentication with DB server to application.

Steps followed.

We are using the default keystore of liberty profile , where we imported the DB certificate and also extracted the applicationcertificate and imported the same oracle DB wallet.

we are using default server.xml file and startup file and java.security files. For making this tcps communication, where exactly we need to make changes

Issue detrails

---

we are able to connect the db through tcp string. But not able to connect by tcps string.

```
       tcp string – thin:jts-user/{password}@//192.168.100.216:1521/vmtestdb
       tcps String - thin:jts_user/{password}@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=192.168.100.216)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=vmtestdb)))
```

Error Code:-

---

Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The ssl protocol specified is not supported.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SSLv2Hello is not a recognized protocol.

For reproducing the issue, we will get the same error when we put tcps string to connect the db.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459086/mutual-ssl-between-was-liberty-profile-and-ibm-http-server/49179323#49179323 - This link was helpful, but somebody cna help with the steps followed to get this ?

Comment: That message seems to indicate that you are using the SSLv2 protocol, which isn't supported by Oracle.  Switching to a supported protocol such as TLS or SSLv3 should resolve the issue.

Comment: We tried to switch the protocol in liberty server by editing the server.xml and startup files. But no luck.. So where we need to switch the protocol, in oracle db side or Liberty server side.